# Recorder.js single data point

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm using [jwegener's recorder.js](https://github.com/jwagener/recorder.js/) for audio recording. I am curious if it is possible to poll the flash from the javascript while the recorder is running to get a "frame" of the audio to build a waveform.

In my imagined pseudocode:

```
function record() {
    Recorder.Record();

    setInterval(function(){
      Recorder.fetchCurrentAudioSnapshot();
    }, 50);
}
```

Ideally that would give me a numerical value that I could use to plot the waveform.

Thanks for any ideas you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

The first thing I did was put the example javascript into an object. Here is the record function I am using:

```
record: function() {
        this.data = [];
        this.poll = '';

        Recorder.record({
            start: function () {
                alert("recording starts now. press stop when youre done. and then play or upload if you want.");
            },
            progress: function (milliseconds) {
                document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = Voiceover.timecode(milliseconds);
            }
        });

        this.waveform = new Waveform({
            container: document.getElementById("voiceover_waveform"),
            interpolate: false
        });
        var ctx = this.waveform.context;

        var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, this.waveform.height);
        gradient.addColorStop(0.0, "#f60");
        gradient.addColorStop(1.0, "#ff1b00");
        this.waveform.innerColor = gradient;

        var i=0;

        this.poll = setInterval(function() {
            Voiceover.data.push(Recorder.PollAudioBuffer());
            Voiceover.waveform.update({
                data: Voiceover.data
            });
        }, 70);
    },
```

This initializes the waveform and sets an interval of 70ms to poll the recorder to get a new datapoint and plot it on the waveform.

In `recorder.js`, I added the following function:

```
PollAudioBuffer: function() {
    try {
        var poll = this.flashInterface().pollAudioBuffer();

        console.log(poll);

        if(poll < 0.15) {
                            // Messing around with the math a bit to improve the effect. 
                            // The final result just has to be between 0 and 1.
            poll = Math.floor((Math.random()*1.5)+1)/10;
        }

        return poll;
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
},
```

Now to the Action Script. In `Recorder.as`, I added my `pollAudioBuffer()` function, which is actually a bit misnamed now.

```
protected function pollAudioBuffer():Number
    {
        return (microphone.activityLevel*2)/100;
    }
```

To get the function to work, you need to add a callback reference to `addExternalInterfaceCallbacks()` in `Recorder.as`:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("pollAudioBuffer",this.pollAudioBuffer);
```

These changes allowed me to create a waveform on the fly. Hope this will help somebody else.

Comment: Would you care to share your new compiled swf file with the pollAudioBuffer added?

Comment: I wasn't allowed to at the time because it was a work project and my boss didn't allow it. And now I don't work there anymore. Hopefully the instructions I listed should get you most of the way there.